# How to perform multiple find() with $slice?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I have the requirement to pull MANY $slice parts of MANY documents.

At the moment I cannot see how to do with, so I have a Parallel Loop which pulls this data for me, however now I am wanting to retrive over 1000 nodes at a time, and this is not becoming performance, especially as the MongoDB C Sharp driver does not support Async queries.

This is the (example but similar) structure:

{
TransactionId: BinData,
Outputs: [ { Data: BinData }, { Data: BinData } ]
}

My code at the moment gets each individually, as so:

```
var outputs = new SpendableOutput[inputArray.Length];

Parallel.ForEach(inputArray, (input, s, i) =>
{
    var transactionQuery = Transactions.Find(Query<TransactionInfo>.EQ(x => x.Hash, input.PrevTxHash))
                                .SetFields(new FieldsBuilder().Slice("o", (int)input.PrevTxOutputIndex, 1)
                                                                .Include("_id"));
    var transaction = transactionQuery.ToArray();
    if (transaction.Length != 0)
    {
        outputs[i] = new SpendableOutput
        {
            TxHash = inputArray[i].PrevTxHash,
            Index = (int)inputArray[i].PrevTxOutputIndex,
            Output = transaction[0].Outputs[0]
        };
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am querying the Transactions collection, "o" field, which is an array of Outputs. From this I want a number of the Outputs. I realize I could ask for all Transactions based on the _id being in my list, and get the Outputs out after they have been retrieved, but many Transactions have very large Output lists from which I only need usually one or two items.

The first way of improving this is to get many slices from one document, such as this (does not work).

```
var transactionQuery = Transactions.Find(Query<TransactionInfo>.EQ(x => x.Hash, input.PrevTxHash))
                            .SetFields(new FieldsBuilder().Slice("o", itemNeededIndex1, 1)
                                                          .Slice("o", itemNeededIndex2, 1)
                                                          .Slice("o", itemNeededIndex3, 1).Include("_id"));
```

Secondly way (must preferred) is for me to send a batch of Query<> objects, as I have many (over 1000 usually) Transaction objects (with associated Outputs to retrieve).

Is there any MongoDB query expert that could suggest an approach to achieving these, or suggest an alternative approach I've not thought about?

EDIT:

The source of the Parent ID and Child Index is an external input which is defining which items could be required to clear a particular balance. They have the ID of the Parent and the index of the Child only. This consists of an array of a Byte Array (Parent Id/Hash) and int (Child Index).

Comment: How do you know which elements you want to slice? Is there some query condition that matches the elements that you want? Will this vary per transaction or is there some set process or rule that determines this based on other fields?

Comment: If you assume it is a Parent - Child relationship here. I am looking for many children, having the Parent Id and the Index of the child. I am looking for a way to get all these records in one mongo call. There may be more than one Child for a Parent to retrieve.

Comment: That part I do understand. My question was how to you know which index values from the array you want to slice? What determines indexes 2,5,7 for example? The other parts of my original comment are the flow in questions from that. I am generally saying your question could be edited to clarify your process and purpose. This is usually the case when you have not received an answer and want to draw some attention to your question.

Comment: There is an external process supplying these values. I simply wish to return only the items of the array I need, which may not be consecutive indexes. I want to do this in one operation, but I do not want to pull the entire parent back as it may be too large.

Comment: Sure. But if you understand my meaning the usage here is odd. Slice implements by it's expected usage, say the last three items, first three items etc. You are asking for specific indexes. That has to come from somewhere. Could you instead match the values? What is the `BinData` here? A UUID or GUID? These are things I mean about clarifying your question. I helps suggest other possible solutions.

Comment: If Slice is implementing its expected results thats fine, what I want to achieve is not possible in this case.

Comment: My Logic here is that if something is producing the required index positions for your process to consume, then something is processing the data already (and probably in not the most efficient way) in order to produce this. You can match "values" in MongoDB and return more than one array member, so there is that. It also stands to reason that whatever is producing the input is following rules, so maybe the processes can be combined. All that has been said is what you think you want may not actually be the solution. Shame to waste a bounty offer with no result for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined that there is no way to achieve this, instead there must be many queries made up and fired at MongoDB.

Also, because the arrays are large it is worth normalizing this data into a new collection, however that does hurt my data size.